# kiwi tcms is not able to search bugs from JIRA

Tags: jira, kiwi-tcms, kiwi

I have integrated JIRA as third party bug tracker in locally deployed TCMS.

as per steps mentioned in the [doc](https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html#configure-bug-trackers)

Integration is successful. [image]

After this step, when i proceed to searching bug (**Home > Search > Search bugs**). TCMS does not list any products/components/version from JIRA !.
I did disable the default bug tracker (with below env variable)

> `>>> os.environ.get("KIWI_DISABLE_BUGTRACKER") 'yes'`

Am i missing something here? help me if there are additional configurations.

Answer (score 0):

> I have integrated JIRA as third party bug tracker in locally deployed TCMS. as per steps mentioned in the doc

If you read the documentation more closely at the top of the above page you will find:

> The extent of integration with 3rd party bug tracking systems is documented in tcms.issuetracker.

which tells you that the functionality you are looking for is not currently supported. If you wish this functionality to be considered for a future release you can open a feature request at https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/new/choose

"Search bugs" is to query the internal bug tracker which you have disabled and this is not related to Jira.

Comment: Thank you Alexander, i have raised new feature request https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/2688.